# ¿Es posible que los textarea que se generen, no se generen con el mismo ID y name?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Poseo este código utilizado para recoger datos de un formulario mediante un textarea. Dicho formulario también posee un botón para generar más textarea.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit(){
            return "Ha intentado salir de esta pagina. Si ha realizado algun cambio en los campos sin hacer clic en el boton Guardar, los cambios se perderan. Seguro que desea salir de esta pagina? ";
        }

        var table_inputs = 0;
        function addTextarea(id, name) {
            var table     = document.getElementById(id);
            var row       = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell      = row.insertCell(0);
            var input     = document.createElement("textarea");
            table_inputs++;
            input.rows    = "4";
            input.cols    = "170";
            input.name    = name + table_inputs;
            input.id      = id + table_inputs;
            var campo     = document.createElement("input");
            campo.type    = "button";
            campo.value   = "Borrar";
            campo.onclick = function () {
                var fila  = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                tbody.removeChild(fila);
            }
            cell.appendChild(input);
            cell.appendChild(campo);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input1) {
            input1.value = "";
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="creador.php" method="post" width="30%">
        <table id="tablafecha" border="3" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Fecha y número</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fecha: <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha"><br>
                    Número: <input type="number" name="numero" id="numero">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tesisTable" border="3" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>TESIS DOCTORAL</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="tesis" id="tesis" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                    <button onclick="addTextarea('tesisTable', 'tesis')" type="button" name="tesis2" id="tesis2">Añadir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </center>
    </form>
```

En otro código, tengo como se recogen y como los represento.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var datos ="<?php foreach( $tesis as $key => $value ): ?><?php echo $value; ?><?php endforeach; ?>";
  var datos2 ="<?php foreach( $subvenciones as $key => $value ): ?><?php echo $value; ?><?php endforeach; ?>";
  var datos3 ="<?php foreach( $otrainfo as $key => $value ): ?><?php echo $value; ?></ul><?php endforeach; ?>";
  var datos4 ="<?php foreach( $actualidad as $key => $value ): ?><?php echo $value; ?><?php endforeach; ?>";
```

¿Como haría para que los nuevos textarea que genero con cada botón creen un array independiente del primero?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. _¿Como haría para que los nuevos textarea que genero con cada botón creen un array independiente del primero?_ ¿Por qué no pones, por ejemplo, en la pregunta cuáles son esos nuevos textarea y cuáles son los arrays que se generan? ¿Y cuáles son esos _cada botón_ o **desde qué botón quieres que se realice lo que quieres**? A veces no es fácil entrar en la lógica del otro para entender el problema. A veces el problema no es el problema, sino que nos hemos decidido por una solución problemática.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte del formulario:

```
        var table_inputs = 0;
        function addTextarea(id, name) {
            var table     = document.getElementById(id);
            var row       = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell      = row.insertCell(0);
            var input     = document.createElement("textarea");
            table_inputs++;
            input.rows    = "4";
            input.cols    = "170";
            input.name    = name + table_inputs;
            input.id      = id + table_inputs;
            var campo     = document.createElement("input");
            campo.type    = "button";
            campo.value   = "Borrar";
            campo.onclick = function () {
                var fila  = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                tbody.removeChild(fila);
            }
            cell.appendChild(input);
            cell.appendChild(campo);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input1) {
            input1.value = "";
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="creador.php" method="post" width="30%">
        <table id="tesisTable" border="3" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>TESIS DOCTORAL</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="tesis" id="tesis" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                    <button onclick="addTextarea('tesisTable', 'tsis')" type="button" name="tesis2" id="tesis2">Añadir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

En la parte de código que recoge los datos y los guarda en un array:

```
 <?php
  $post = [];

  if( !empty( $_POST ) )
  {
    $filter = array_filter($_POST);
    $post   = $filter;
  }
  $tesis        = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^tesis[0-9]*/i', array_keys( $post ) ) ) );
  $tsis         = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^tsis[0-9]*/i', array_keys( $post ) ) ) );
?>
```

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: @muriano, le quedan 46h creo

Comment: ¿Alguien entendió que quiso decir?

Comment: Nadiesssss... Pero su avatar lo dice todo. =)